# How would you go about spell checking player inputted words?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text, autocorrect, spelling

The game I want to make invloves players typing sentences, but my problem is I need to check the spelling of each word in their sentence, and possibly offer them what word they may have meant. Does anyone know how I could go about doing that?

Comment: Please include any code that you've tried. See more info [here](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: As your question stands it would be off-topic since the answer is: Either provide a library of valid words and implement a spell check for all of them or use a library that already does this. -> Questions asking for a tool/library/full solution/tutorial/etc are off-topic on StackOverlow

Comment: You can however use https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.InputType.AutoCorrect.html which at least e.g. on Android will provide autocorrect

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, you can use the API of Google and Bing to spell check. there are also some 3rd party dll's that you can use together with the OpenOfice spelling dictionary.

Have a look at https://github.com/loresoft/NetSpell